# linking errors after moving my class to "vc/include/" directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I am having  "unresolved external symbol" linking error for a simple class i wrote along with a header file in VS 2008 using c++.

I moved this class to VS 2008's include directory, so that I don't have to copy the files from one project to other every time creating a new project.

I included the header file in some new project, the file got included alright, I can also see the list functions and data members inside the object of that class file, [ VS 2008 shows me this list after I type '.' ]

But this is not the weird part, the weird part is, the files which I moved to include directory works fine in the original project in which I wrote them.

Comment: Was there a cpp file involved in the original project that implemented anything?

Comment: Yes, it was involved in the previous project, I later moved it to include dir, from there as well it was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as including the header file in your new project, you will need to add the implementing cpp file, otherwise you will get

> "unresolved external symbol"

link errors.

Comment: that does it. 
a rookie mistake from my part.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

to understand "unresolved external symbol" issue please refer to:
[Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-no-idea)