# protected function call c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
Class Base() {
protected:
    void foo();
}
Class Derived : public Base {
    void bar();
}

void Derived::bar(){
    foo();    //this causes an error.
}
```

I know i'm probably missing something obvious but I've been going round in circles for an hour. How do I call a protected function in a derived class?

Comment: What error does it cause?

Comment: have you tried Base::foo()?

Comment: Note that the bar() method in Derived class is private, since that is the default visibility for a method in a class with no access specifiers.

Comment: I have tried Base::foo() and this->foo(), neither of which work. causes this error:Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: unsigned int __thiscall ShaderProgram::LoadShader(unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?LoadShader@ShaderProgram@@IAEIIABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall BasicProgram::BasicProgram(void)"

Comment: from:      class BasicProgram : public ShaderProgram

Comment: Sounds like you've neglected to add whatever .cpp file contains the definition of `Base::foo()` to your project file (or whatever the equivalent is for your build tool)

Comment: Hard to figure out with the code sample you gave.

Comment: -1 for not including the error, and for not posting actual code.  You assumed that your problem was related to the method being `protected`, but you were wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The error that appears in the comments is a linker error, so have you checked that:

- You have provided a definition of the protected function
  E.g.

  ```
  class Base {
  protected:
      void foo() {
           std::cout
  ```
- The file containing the definition has been compiled (added into the makefile / CMakefile / project file)
- It is linked into the final executable
- See [Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-no-idea) and [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

It's hard to tell any more without more info.

---

Also, your code contains invalid syntax, which causes error(s):

- `class` is lower case
- No brackets after class name
- `;` after class definition

The following code works (until it gets to the linker) on `g++ version 4.9.0`:

```
class Base {
protected:
    void foo();
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void bar();
};

void Derived::bar(){
    foo();
}
```

Comment: @Robomoo Asking about problems with actual code by providing pseude-code does not really work, usually... How do you expect the pseudo-code to show the problem? How do you expect the answerers to distinguish pseudo-problems from the real problem?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are missing the foo() implementation. In addition to the syntax errors commented by other users and the public statement. The following code compiles.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
protected:
    void foo() {std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void bar();
};

void Derived::bar(){
    foo();    //this causes an error.
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    Derived d;
    d.bar();

    return 0;
}
```