# Using vsvars32.bat - Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, compiler-errors

I am not familiar with C/C++ but I have to use vsvars32.bat to build an executable file. When I run vsvars32.bat i get some `unresolved external symbol` errors. I did a little bit of research and it seems that they occur because the lib that contains the definition are not included ([Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-in-object-files)).

Here is a one of the error:
`libxml2.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func`

I was provided the `libxml2.lib` file. I'm guessing that I'm getting this error because I need to copy it someplace where `vsvars32.bat` will look for it. I've been looking through the `vsvars32.bat` file and it looks like there's three libraries that are defined:

- Windows SDK (`%WindowsSdkDir%`)
- NETFXSDK (`%NETFXSDKDir%`)
- UCRTVersion (`%UCRTVersion%`)

I was able to locate the NETFXSDK library folders on my machine but not the two others. I also noticed that I don't have any system variables named `WindowsSdkDir`, `NETFXSDKDir` or `UCRTVersion`. Is there something else that I should install or run? Am I on the totally wrong track?

Comment: Not that it would make any difference but use `vcvarsall.bat` located under _%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC_ (that calls `vcvars32.bat` if no arguments given). Also, you need to be careful about the CPU architecture (it must be consistent across all modules). What is the _linker_ command? Note: _Windows SDK_ is automatically installed by _VStudio_ (btw: what is your version?) or can be also installed separately. I have no reference of _%UCRTVersion%_ in my file (_VStudio 10.0_).

Comment: I used `vcvarsall.bat` and as you said it didn't make a difference. I have Visual Studio Express 14.0. I have not written any of the files that need to be built. They are all included in the SDK downloadable here: https://resources.qtronic.de/fmusdk/FmuSdk_reference.html#installation

Comment: OK, what exactly are you trying to do? There are many pieces of the puzzle that simply don't connect. There is _VStudio_, then there is the _FMUSDK_ and _libxml2_ (and probably some other code of your own) that are totally unrelated. _vsvars32.bat_ is not used to build anything, it simply sets some env vars (which will be useful during build time). Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and don't let us guess what your error might be, and how can it be solved.