# Definition of virtual function not found in another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, dll, virtual

A project consists of the following class (further functions are omitted):

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass {
    public:
        virtual void print();
};

// MyClass.cpp 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
void MyClass::print() {
    // empty
}
```

In ANOTHER project a class is derived from `MyClass`. The `print` function is not overwritten. In the linking step after the compilation a definition of the function `print` can't be found ("unresolved external symbol" error). How can I fix this issue? The project with the `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp` is referenced in the project.

Edit: Development Environment is VS 2015 on Win10 x64. If I remove the keyword `virtual` or move MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp to the other project the error doesn't occur anymore.

Edit 2: Both projects are dynamic libraries (DLLs).

Comment: Guess you're not linking your cpp files correctly.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-in-object-files

Comment: What is your environment? UNIX/Linux/Mac/VS/Something else?

Comment: What is your development environment? How is your setup? How does MySubClass look like? Your example is unfortunately neither minimal nor working... It is not easy to help that way.

Comment: @UKMonkey This is the more complete duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 0):

The project containing `MyClass.cpp` will generate a `.lib` file when it is built. That library file must be added to the other project so that it can be linked in, telling that project that it can find the code in the other DLL.

Comment: The directory with the lib is added at "Additional Library Directories" and the lib itself at "Additional Dependencies" in the project properties.

Comment: @user1056903 I'm not sure that simply adding it to the project properties dependencies is enough. Unfortunately it isn't anything I've had to do myself lately so I don't have a specific step to follow.