# Algebraic Tree Expression C++ error: Unresolved External Symbol "Public:_thiscall AlgebraicTreeExpression::~AlgebraicTreeExpression(void) ..."

Tags: c++, tree

I'm working on a homework problem in C++ in which I'm trying to write a wrapper AlgebraicTreeExpression class around a base AlgebraicTreeNode class for parsing and calculating algebraic equations based on an input string. The 3 errors I'm getting are:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AlgebraicTreeExpression::~AlgebraicTreeExpression(void)" (??1AlgebraicTreeExpression@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CMakeLists.txt    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Calc6.cpp.obj

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AlgebraicTreeExpression::AlgebraicTreeExpression(char const *)" (??0AlgebraicTreeExpression@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main 1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CMakeLists.txt    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Calc6.cpp.obj

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: char * __thiscall AlgebraicTreeExpression::toString(void)const " (?toString@AlgebraicTreeExpression@@QBEPADXZ) referenced in function _main 1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CMakeLists.txt    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Calc6.cpp.obj
```

The relevant parts of AlgebraicTreeExpression.cpp are:

```
AlgebraicTreeExpression::AlgebraicTreeExpression():
  _root(new AlgebraicTreeNode()) {
}
AlgebraicTreeExpression::~AlgebraicTreeExpression() {
    if (_root != 0) delete _root;
}
char* AlgebraicTreeExpression::toString() const {
    return _root->AlgebraicTreeNode::toString();
}
// parser constructor
AlgebraicTreeExpression::AlgebraicTreeExpression(const char* expression):
  _root(new AlgebraicTreeNode(expression)) {
}
```

The relevant parts of AlgebraicTreeNode.cpp are:

```
AlgebraicTreeNode::~AlgebraicTreeNode() {
    delete this;
}

AlgebraicTreeNode::AlgebraicTreeNode() {
    //Default Constructor
    //this->id();
    //count();
    //_parent = (AlgebraicTreeNode*)0;
    _childLeft = 0; _childRight = 0;
    _type = AlgebraicTreeNodeType::INVALID;
    _value = 0;
}

AlgebraicTreeNode::AlgebraicTreeNode(AlgebraicTreeNode& src) {
    //Copy Constructor
    if (src._childLeft != (AlgebraicTreeNode*)(0)) {
        this->setChildLeft(src._childLeft);
        AlgebraicTreeNode(_childLeft);
    }
    if (src._childRight != (AlgebraicTreeNode*)(0)) {
        this->setChildRight(src._childRight);
        AlgebraicTreeNode(_childRight);
    }
    if (src._type == AlgebraicTreeNodeType::NUMBER) {
        _value = src._value;
        _type = src._type;
        _childLeft = 0; _childRight = 0;
    }
}
void AlgebraicTreeNode::setChildLeft(AlgebraicTreeNode* childLeft) {
    _childLeft = childLeft;
    _childLeft->_parent = this;
}

void AlgebraicTreeNode::setChildRight(AlgebraicTreeNode* childRight) {
    _childRight = childRight;
    _childRight->_parent = this;
}
char* AlgebraicTreeNode::toString() const {
    unsigned N = this->_toStringLength();
    char* str = new char[N];
    memset(str, '\0', N * sizeof(char));
    AlgebraicTreeNode::_toString(str);
    return str;
  return (char*)0;
}
AlgebraicTreeNode::AlgebraicTreeNode(const char* expression) {
    unsigned length = _parseExpression(expression);
}

// returns length of parsed substring 
unsigned AlgebraicTreeNode::_parseExpression(const char* expression) {
    static int integers[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> number(integers, integers + sizeof(integers) / sizeof(int));
    unsigned length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<int>::size_type sz = number.size();


  if (*expression == '(') {
      length += 1;
      this->setChildLeft(new AlgebraicTreeNode());
      this->_value = 0;

      length += this->_childLeft->_parseExpression(expression + length);
      if (*(expression + length) == '+') {
          this->_type = AlgebraicTreeNodeType::ADD;
          length += 1;
      }
      else if (*(expression + length) == '-') {
          this->_type = AlgebraicTreeNodeType::SUBTRACT;
          length += 1;
      }
      else if (*(expression + length) == '*') {
          this->_type = AlgebraicTreeNodeType::MULTIPLY;
          length += 1;
      }
      else if (*(expression + length) == '/') {
          this->_type = AlgebraicTreeNodeType::DIVIDE;
          length += 1;
      }
      this->setChildRight(new AlgebraicTreeNode());
      length += this->_childRight->_parseExpression(expression + length);
      length += 1; //Placeholder for )
      return length;
  }
  while (i != sz) {
      printf("%i, %i\n", atoi(expression), number[i]);
      std::cout << typeid(atoi(expression)).name() << typeid(number[i]).name() << std::endl;
      if (atoi(expression + length) == number[i]) {
          this->_type = AlgebraicTreeNodeType::NUMBER;
          length += this->_parseNumber(expression + length);
          return length;
      }
      i++;
  }
  return length;
}

unsigned AlgebraicTreeNode::_parseNumber(const char* expression) {
  //unsigned length = 0;
  char *endptr;
  double value = strtod(expression,&endptr);
  this->_value = value;
  unsigned length = endptr - expression;
  return length;
}
unsigned AlgebraicTreeNode::_toStringLength() const {
   unsigned length = 1024;

   return length;
 }
 unsigned AlgebraicTreeNode::_toString(char* str) const {
   unsigned ntemp = 0;
   if (this->_type == INVALID) {
       return 0;
   }
   if (isOperation()) {

       ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), "(");

       if (this->_childLeft != (AlgebraicTreeNode*)0) {

           ntemp += this->_childLeft->_toString(str + ntemp);
       }
       if (_type == ADD) {
           ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), "+");
       }
       else if (_type == SUBTRACT) {
           ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), "-");
       }
       else if (_type == MULTIPLY) {
           ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), "*");
       }
       else if (_type == DIVIDE) {
           ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), "/");
       }
       if (this->_childRight != (AlgebraicTreeNode*)0) {
           ntemp += this->_childRight->_toString(str + ntemp);
       }
       ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), ")");
   }
   else if (isNumber()) {
       double thisvalue = this->_value;
       ntemp += sprintf((str + ntemp), "%.0f", thisvalue);
   }
   return ntemp;
 }
```

This is likely a small fix but thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking together with the AlgebraicTreeExpression.cpp object file? (i.e. for MSVC it must be either in the same project, or if it is a library, it needs to be specified that you want to link it).

Other than that, refer to here: [Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-in-object-files)

Btw.

```
AlgebraicTreeNode::~AlgebraicTreeNode() {
    delete this;
}
```

please don't do that, call `delete` on the object instead, which will call the destructor and free the memory (not the other way around calling the `delete` from inside the destructor as you have here).

(this will especially bite you hard if the object is created on the stack)