# How to add Switch Qml to qt widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qquickwidget

I have a qml file `ToggleSwitch.qml` which I want to import to my widgets. Basically I want to integrate qml with widget

**ToggleSwitch.qml**

```
Switch  
{  
    checked:true  
}
```

In `Mainwindow.cpp` I want do something like this

**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget;   
quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Resources/ToggleSwitch.qml"));  
QVBoxLayout *vBox = new QVBoxLayout;  
vBox->addWidget(quickWidget);
```

I tried this above code but it does not work. It throws error unresolved external symbol

Comment: **Error**  Mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QQuickWidget::~QQuickWidget(void)" (__imp_??1QQuickWidget@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl QQuickWidget::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQQuickWidget@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)

Comment: .qml is in Resource folder

Comment: QT       += core gui qml quick  

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets  

TARGET = Sample  
TEMPLATE = app  


DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS  

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000      
SOURCES += \  
        main.cpp \  
        mainwindow.cpp  

HEADERS += \  
        mainwindow.h  

FORMS += \  
        mainwindow.ui  

RESOURCES += \  
    resources.qrc

Comment: You shall find the solution base on the error message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-in-object-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `QQuickWidget` you must add the module `quickwidgets`, add the following to the .pro:

```
QT += quickwidgets
```

Also do not forget to include the header:

```
#include <QQuickWidget>
```

If you are in windows you must use windowdeployqt to obtain all the necessary dlls to execute your application, more information the following link:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Added but somehow in qml I am not able to import QtQuick.Controls . It prompts me to add QML_IMPORT_PATH

Comment: @Rubina 
What is your version of Qt?

Comment: I am using qt 5.9.4

Comment: @Rubina 
reinstall your Qt, surely that attribute was not established correctly.

Comment: Still getting errors File not found unresolved externals error I am getting when I tried in different pc

Comment: @Rubina 
You have to use windeployqt to get the dlls that are needed, read the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how to use windeployqt